# How to save bmp image from a bytearray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have a bytearray as well as image height and width which holds the RGBA BMP image data. I would like to save it to a file.

I tried with PIL image library but with no lock.

```
stream = BytesIO(b_array)
Image.open(stream)
image = Image.open(stream)
stream.close()
image.save("test.bmp")
```

The error received

PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001E522690D10>

Any help here?

BTW, I don't need BMP, any popular image file format works with me.

Comment: Already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53693315/6146054

Comment: Thanks, following the above and I am coming with the answer myself for others to refer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
im = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height))
im.frombytes(source)
im.save("test.bmp")
```